# Pool de conexão PHP:PDO com PostgreSQL, o que usar?

Tags: php, pdo, postgresql, apache, ubuntu

Pensando no seguinte esquema: 
Servidor linux (Pode ser Ubuntu Server) +
PHP utilizando PDO +
PostgreSQL +
Servidor HTTP Apache +
Algum pool de conexão

Gostaria de alguma dica de pool (que seja confiável) para gerenciar as conexões com o banco de dados. Não sei se PDO lida tao bem quanto um POOL de conexão.

Grato desde já!

Comment: PDO lida otimamente com as conexões de dados

Comment: Certo, mas imagine um número de 500 conexões simultâneas. Não seria melhor utilizar um pool para gerenciar isso? @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho

Comment: cara, primeiramente, os pools de conexão são da camada do database, portanto, vai ter de ser configurado no db, dai, como voce especificou PostgreSQL tanto faz voce usar PDO ou pg_conect pois o seu dabase é quem tá provendo o pool, eu, note bem, nunca abondanaria o PDO, é muito mais versatil